# put data to constructor in another class

Tags: java, list, vector

i got a class call ClientIdBandwidth.java as shown at below

```
public class ClientIdBandwidth
{
private int clientID;
private int bandwidth;

public ClientIdBandwidth(int clientID , int bandwidth)
{
    this.clientID = clientID;
    this.bandwidth = bandwidth;
}

public int getClientID()
{
    return clientID;
}

public int getBandwidth()
{
    return bandwidth;
}
}
```

i want to call the ClientIdBandwidth constructor and and put the data to the constructor? below is the code that i have do so far :

```
public class connectNode
{
private List[] connection;
private int totalClients;
totalClients = clientList.size(); //get the size from another class 
connection = new Vector[totalClients]; //  

for(int i = 0; i<totalClients; i++) 
    {
        connection[i] = new Vector(); 
    } 
for(int i = 0; i<totalClients; i++)
    {       
        int ID = (int)clientList.get(i);
        ClientIdBandwidth cib = new ClientIdBandwidth(ID,'0');
            }
```

after that, i have no idea how to continued on . can anyone teach me ? thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

sorry that i didnt make it clear.

i am now doing a p2p simulator. i have a text file :

0;2;100; // Node 0 connect to Node 2 with 100kbps

1;5;200; // Node 1 connect to Node 5 with 200kbps

i have class that will read the txt file. and it have put the total how many node(in example above is 4 which is Node 0,2,1,5) inside a list. now i want to set like node 0 is connect to node 2 with bandwidth to a vector.

Comment: It would *really* help if you'd indent the code in your question sensibly. It's not clear what you mean by "put the data to the constructor" either.

Comment: `how to continued on` - For that you need to tell, where you want to reach? I mean, what do you want to achieve? Also, your constructor takes `integer`, and you are passing `character`. Although that would work, but may behave unexpectedly, if that was not intentional.

Comment: what you want to do actually?? please explain

Comment: You are arleady passing data to ClientIDBandwidth constructor (but as Rohit Jain said, you are passing a String instead of an int). You can now call your getter methods. What do you want to do next?

Comment: @eSuarez.. No, I didn't say `String`. I said `character`. Passing String would fail to compile.

Comment: Yeh, you have created a `CreateIdBandwidth` called `cib` do you want to do something with that inside the `for` loop?

Comment: @RohitJain yes, my bad. Sorry for the big typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work unexpected way in most of the cases. Your constructor is expecting 2 integer parameters, but you are passing one integer and one 'char' type. That might be the reason you are stuck/code not working/incorrect result etc (you haven't said the exact issue).

Or else, Your `ClientBandwith` object is getting created inside a for loop. It is created and destroyed all inside that for loop. At the end, when for loop is done, there will be no instances. So after the for loop, the `ClientBandwith` class will remain as it is, without  EXISTING objects, so you can't get anything using getters. In this case, you will not even notice what has happened. So you are complaining you can't "put the data into the constructor" because the instance is getting destroyed?

Apart from that,

1. the 'Vector' is slow and outdated. Use `ArrayList`.
2. If you know the exact size of the Vector, I think going for an Array is a good alternative
3. You are creating a Vector inside a Vector. Is that is really useful here?
4. Use Generics
5. You are using 2 for loops. But as you can see, your work can be done by 1 for loop.
6. Follow Java Naming standards. Your second class is starting with a simple letter
7. if you want all the data in the Vector to be loaded to the constructor, your system will not work. Accept a `List` type as an argument
8. **when you ask a question, tell us what you really want to do**